# getting error while running springboot application like application failed to start

Tags: spring-boot

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method updateAssignmentDetails in com.glomoSpring.service.AssignmentServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.glomoSpring.entity.AssignmentDetails' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.glomoSpring.entity.AssignmentDetails' in your configuration.

Comment: Paste the relevant code so that people can help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use @Entity in AssignmentDetails class to get bean